# Classify singularities for $f(z) = \frac{z}{e^{3z}-1} $ and find residue

Tags: complex-analysis

Classify singularities for $f(z) =  \frac{z}{e^{3z}-1} $.
I tried to solve $e^{3z} = 1 $ with $3z = \log 1$ which gives $z = 2k\pi/3$.

If this is correct then how do I find residue? I tried to use the theorem $p(z)/q'(z)$ and that gives infinitely many different residues.

Help please

Comment: when $z \to 0$ : $e^z = 1+z + \mathcal{O}(z^2)$. and yes it reduces to computing $p(\rho)/q'(\rho)$ at $\rho = 2 i k \pi /3$ ...

Comment: let me ask something : what are the poles are residues of $\frac{1}{e^{3z}-1}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a set of simple (i.e., first order) poles at $z=i2\ell \pi/3$ for integer $\ell \ne 0$.

A straightforward way to determine the resides at the poles $z=i2\ell \pi/3$ for integer $\ell\ne 0$ is by evaluating the limit(s) using L'Hospital's Rule

$$\begin{align}\lim_{z\to i2\ell \pi/3} \frac{z(z-i2\ell \pi/3)}{e^{3z}-1}&=\lim_{z\to i2\ell \pi/3}\frac{z+(z-i2\ell \pi/3)}{3e^{3z}}\\\\
&=\frac{i2\ell \pi/3}{3e^{i2\ell \pi}}\\\\
&=i2\pi \ell/9
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the residue at $z=i2\pi \ell/3$ is given by

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\text{Res}\left(\frac{z}{e^{3z}-1}, z=i2\ell \pi/3\right)=i2\pi \ell/9}$$

Comment: Why the down vote??

Comment: Nestro, please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark